# What is the significance of {*} when used with args like {*}args in tcl

Tags: tcl

What is the significance of `{*}` when used with `args` like `{*}args`?
For instance: how is using the following in a class method

```
next a {*}$args b
```

different from using

```
next a $args b
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's the argument/list expansion operator. It converts a list into many single words.

It's documented as part of the tcl syntax rules: http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/Tcl.htm. It is rule number 5.

For example, say you have a list:

```
set foo {a b c d}
```

and you call the command:

```
bar $foo
```

The command will be interpreted as:

```
bar "a b c d"
```

But if instead you do:

```
bar {*}$foo
```

Then the command will be interpreted as:

```
bar a b c d
```

Comment: And I strongly suggest you read through the tcl syntax rules. Unlike other languages tcl's entire syntax rules fits into a single page (there are only 12 rules)

Comment: The `{*}` syntax (it's _technically_ not an operator) was added in Tcl 8.5 to address the difficulty of using `eval` correctly in a lot of use cases. The problem? Most uses of `eval` were buggy in bad ways, and the whole thing was usually slow too.

Answer (score 1):

You can see the difference for yourself in the interactive shell by putting the command `list` in front of the invocation:

```
list next a {*}$args b 
list next a $args b
```

Set `args` to some value (preferably some list value), run the above, and you'll see what the invocation actually looks like.

Answer (score 0):

`{*}` splices the element of a list as individual arguments, not the whole list as a single argument.